# Convert String to XML Document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

Saw this example on the jQuery examples page for Ajax:

```
var xmlDocument = [create xml document];
$.ajax({
        url: "page.php",
        processData: false,
        data: xmlDocument,
        success: someFunction
    });
```

How do I take a string like:

```
var t = '<foo><bar>something</bar></foo>';
```

And convert that to a XML DOM object? cross-browser?

**UPDATE**:
Please see comments to karim79's answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Wrap it in a jQuery object. Then use jQuery's normal DOM manipulation methods on it.

```
var t = $('<foo><bar>something</bar></foo>');

//loop over 'bar' nodes
t.find('bar').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you want to convert it back to a plain string (after modifying it for example) you can do it like so:

```
//then convert it back to a string
//for IE 
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var str = t.xml;
    alert(str);
 }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else {
   var str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(t);
   alert(str);
}
```

EDIT: The [$.ajax manual says](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) (on the processData option):

> By default, data passed in to the data
>   option as an object (technically,
>   anything other than a string) will be
>   processed and transformed into a query
>   string, fitting to the default
>   content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
>   If you want to send DOMDocuments, or
>   other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.

So if you're passing a jQuery object to the server, you'll need to set that to **true**, or omit it altogether (it is set to **true** by default). Hope that helped.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting something wrong in the $.ajax call. I did wrap it like you said. Then my log on the server shows I'm passing in: [object Object]

What should I try now?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong with .ajax() ? I just passed it as a string and it worked. weird. Does this have something to do with the processData option? or another option I'm not turning on?

Comment: @Tyndall - see my edit. Basically, if you're passing an XML string to the server, the setting you currently have is correct (processData : false. If you pass the jQuery object, you'll need to either get rid of that option or set it to true.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the processData - "jQuery in Action" didn't explain as well as you did in 4 sentences.

Comment: Just a note that this fails in IE9 + quirks mode. Not a huge surprise, but something to be aware of at least.

Comment: IE9 supports the XMLSerialize, hence use the following check for IE `if (window.ActiveXObject && (new XMLSerializer()) === undefined) {`

Comment: This worked great for a Windows 8 Metro app where I needed to store the XML as text in local storage, read it, and then process is into anonymous objects. I didn't have to rework any of my existing (which was expecting responseXML) at all. Thanks! +1

Comment: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '<foo><bar>something</bar></foo>' is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 11):

Just a heads up on calling find - if it's a top level element you need to use filter instead.

```
var t = $('<foo><bar>something</bar></foo>');

//loop over 'foo' nodes
t.filter('foo').each(function () {
  alert($(this).find('bar').text());
});
```

Comment: @pubb - you are right, I skipped over that detail as I always loop over the second-level elements. +1 for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the conversion without jQuery. This is taken from Mozilla's [DOMParser Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
// Create a DOMParser
var parser = new DOMParser();

// Use it to turn your xmlString into an XMLDocument
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
```

Comment: You made my day man !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Love Youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code for convert your xml tags to text

```
var temp_var = $("<p/>").append($(your_xml_data)).htML()
```

Answer (score 0):

rock solid code. working perfectly in all browsers.

```
var xmlFields = $("<root><reports name='report 1'><item 
               field='ord_num' desc='Order    Number'/></reports></root>");
alert(xmlFields[0].outerHTML);
```

Comment: This only works because jQuery has created HTML nodes for these. For something where jQuery is treating them like XML nodes (like `$($.parseXML("<xml></xml>")`), this will not work.