# Parsing prototype AJAX.response XML in IE

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I have an xml webservice which I'm fetching using PrototypeJS. The xml has the correct content type and is well-formed, and looks like this:

```
<GetTokenResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetTokenResult>F655100D64F098F0AC33AFF414A4A0D5</GetTokenResult>
</GetTokenResponse>
```

The AJAX request is completing successfully, and I can access the `GetTokenResult` node in both IE and FF but can only get the text content of the node in FF. My code is below:

```
node = transport.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('GetTokenResult')[0];
rawToken = (document.all) ? node.innerText : node.textContent;
```

I've tried innerText and innerHTML, as well as children[0] and a few other chance guesses but IE returns 'undefined' when I access rawToken.

Anyone able to lend a hand? Thanks, Adam

Comment: Your xml has lowercase `<gettokenresult>`. If as you say the MIME type is correct (`text/xml`), then `getElementsByTagName` becomes case-sensitive. FYI....

Comment: Thanks - the case was lost when I copied and pasted - the original doc is in title case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @adam: in that case (no pun intended ;) see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the node value as:

```
rawToken = node.firstChild.data;
```

This should work across all modern browsers, as well as IE.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text content, use firstChild.nodeValue

Answer (score -1):

`node = transport.responseXML` - this is correct.

You end up with "node" as your XML in **string** format. Strip the rest. You need to turn the string into an XML document before you can manipulate it directly.

See: [Convert String to XML Document in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript)

or see: http://www.discussweb.com/html-css-javascript-coding-techniques/3308-convert-ordinary-string-into-xml.html

Comment: Thanks, but Prototype automatically converts it to XML, hence why I can access the node (but not the node content)

Comment: `responseXML`, *if available*, is always a DOM document object, regardless of the ajax library used.