# How to convert string to XML object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript) question already existing, but it has given me no luck.

I have an application which loads a physicial XML document via the following method:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: fileName,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        // etc...
    }
});
```

I parse the XML and convert it into a string which is saved into a variable so that it can easily be stored in a database. How can I now convert the data in this variable back into an XML object so that it can be parsed as such?

Comment: what's your data might look like?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Non-jQuery version:

```
var parseXml;

if (window.DOMParser) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" && new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    parseXml = function() { return null; }
}

var xmlDoc = parseXml("<foo>Stuff</foo>");
if (xmlDoc) {
    window.alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName);
}
```

Since jQuery 1.5, you can use [`jQuery.parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), which works in exactly the same way as the above code:

```
var xmlDoc = jQuery.parseXML("<foo>Stuff</foo>");
if (xmlDoc) {
    window.alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName);
}
```

Comment: +1 It's not just non-jQuery, this actually parses XML properly, unlike the jQuery parser.

Comment: I was actually looking for a jQuery solution, although I know I did not specify. I found your answer very useful though, had not considered this method before.

Comment: +1 in addition to Anurags's comment: jQuery messed up my valid XML (created document was just wrong) and is not a valid solution for parsing XML! It can be used to query the document, but not to create it properly

Comment: isn't ActiveXObject deprecated in most modern browsers?

Comment: @mmcrae: I believe it only ever worked in IE on Windows. The ActiveX branch is there as a fallback for versions of IE (version 9 and onwards have `DOMParser`), which was more of a concern in 2010 than it is now.

Answer (score 7):

With jquery, you can use `$.parseXML(str)`, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 3):

If it's still in XML format you should be able to just wrap it in the jQuery function and start using jQuery to parse through it. For example:

```
$(xmlStringFromDB).find('foo');
```

Comment: If xmlStringFromDB is still a string, then that would force a string to XML each time you use it. If you need it just once, or can link all your request, you're certainly fine, but otherwise you should save that in a (temporary) variable.