# Why $(xmlContent).find("..").text() returns empty string?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why text() returns empty string on MyPage.aspx ?
.find and .filter do find "imagesPaths" node.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function MyFunction(albumNb) 
{    
//xmlContent = "<images><imagePaths>2</imagePaths><imageTitles>title1,title2,title3, 
//title4</imageTitles></images>"

$.ajax({
    url: "MyPage.aspx?albumNb=1",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
       var xmlContent = res.xml;             
       $imagePaths = $(xmlContent).find("imagePaths").text();  //returns empty string, Why? 
       //$imagePaths = $(xmlContent).filter("imagePaths").text(); //also returns empty string 

    }
 });

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you parsed the XML yet?

Comment: Can you show us the XML that you are `GET`ting with your `AJAX` call? As @tymeJV suggested, is it actually `application/xml` or is it simply an XML string?

Comment: what is `res`? is it an object? a string? you have no dataType and haven't given us the raw response therefore we have no way of knowing what you are receiving. It could be JSON, XML, Text, HTML, we don't know.

Comment: var xmlContent value is mentioned above $.ajax call

Comment: @KarenSlon It seems that xmlContent is simply an XML string. [You need to turn it into an XML object.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054108/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Try with `var xmlContent = $.parseXML(res.xml);`

Comment: res is object and it's xml assigned to xmlContent variable

Comment: .parseXML does not work because JQuery version is 1.4.2

Comment: sorry, version is  1.3.2

Comment: See my comment for a [non-jquery version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054108/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-object-in-javascript).

Comment: Damn...I'm assuming the jQuery version is out of your control, yes?