# ExtJs 4 - Convert JS object to xml

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, extjs4.2

Im using ExtJs 4.2.1.

Is there an "easy" way to convert JS object to xml? I mean a simple function like:

```
Ext.JSON.encode(object);
```

To convert object to Json.

Lets say the following object for example:

```
Root:
  Child1
  Child2
  Child3
```

To the following xml:

```
<Root>
   <Child1> some value </Child1>
   <Child2> some value </Child2>
   <Child3> some value </Child3>
</Root>
```

I was trying to search it in the documentation, but didn't came to any solution like that.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing built in to ExtJS. You'll have to find a 3rd party script, or write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used this [nice script](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) for the conversion.

Hopefully Sencha will add built in functions for encoding xml in future versions.

Comment: won't it be a big perf impact doing the conversion in the browser memory?

Comment: I agree. But I can't change the server code + My Objects are not so big that it will impact the performance.

Answer (score 0):

make a XML string using Json data and convert the XML string to XML object

To convert string to XML go through the following link 
[How to convert string to XML object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054108/how-to-convert-string-to-xml-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it is using a middle tier Java class. Lot of java libraries available to convert JSON to XML like Jackson, eclipsemoxy

Answer (score 0):

I did wrote one method while using EXT JS 4, i got the same problem for conversion of Javascript object to XML. this one handles Array Objects also. i have only considered my special cases non other.. so feel free to make any changes..

```
    convertJsToXML: function (rec, rootNode) {
    var xmlString = "";
    var withoutRoot = false;
    for (var object in rec) {
        if (!isNaN(object)) {
            withoutRoot = true;
            xmlString += this.convertJsToXML(rec[object], rootNode);
        } else if (typeof rec[object] == 'object') {
            xmlString += this.convertJsToXML(rec[object], object);
        } else if (rec[object] != null && rec[object] != "") {
            xmlString += "<" + object + ">" + rec[object] + "</" + object + ">";
        }
    }
    if (!withoutRoot)
        xmlString = "<" + rootNode + ">" + xmlString + "</" + rootNode + ">";
    return xmlString;
}
```