# convert a string to xml doc with jquery or the other way round

Tags: jquery

i am trying to convert a string  to an xml document to read the verious nodes  or to append a new node with jquery and there after convert it back to a string again. can anyone help me on the please.
this is a snippet of my code

```
xmldoc.find('ROOT').append(
    '<USER><ENAME>'+ $(this).find('ENAME').text() +
     '</ENAME><OPERATOR>'+$(this).find('OPERATOR').text() +
     '</OPERATOR><PNR>'+$(this).find('PNR').text() +
     '<PNR></USER>'
);

if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    xmldocStr = xmldoc.xml;
}
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else {
    xmldocStr = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmldoc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a jQuery object.

```
var t = $('<foo><bar>something</bar></foo>');

//loop over 'bar' nodes
t.find('bar').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

And to convert it back to a string:

```
//then convert it back to a string
//for IE 
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var str = t.xml;
    alert(str);
 }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else {
   var str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(t);
   alert(str);
}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript