# WCF Service returns an XML, how to prase using jquery?

Tags: jquery

i am calling an api for registration and if everything goes well then api returns an xml file

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\u000a<successNotification>\u000a\u0009<message>Successful web registration<\/message>\u000a\u0009<registrationId>22342347<\/registrationId>\u000a<\/successNotification>"
```

if something wrong then it returns a line of message

`you are missing something`

my question is: how can i display message regardless whether it returns xml or just line of message:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:4126/service.svc/alert', { phoneNumber: '01231231233' },
   function (data) {
      var result = $(data).find('message').html;
      display.innerHTML = result;
 });
```

Comment: Is the missing `'` for your `phoneNumber` var a typo?

Comment: To start, your question is missing a single quote. Fix: `{ phoneNumber: '01231231233' }` or `{ phoneNumber: 01231231233 }` (but the second option will interpret the number in octal, which is probably not what you want).

Comment: If the API returns an XML file, you probably shouldn't be using "$.getJSON()" ...

Comment: @Matt: my question is more towards parsing the xml file i am not sure i understand what you trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), return a string even when you are returning XML and parse it browser side with [.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) would be one way.

```
$.get('http://localhost:4126/service.svc/alert', 
   { phoneNumber: '01231231233' },
   function (data) {
      var result;
      if(data.indexOf("<") >= 0) { // test for a character in XML but not the string
          var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
          result = $(xmlDoc).find('message').html();
      } else {
          result = data;
      }
      display.innerHTML = result;
 },
 "text");
```

Comment: error `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method` on the line - `$.parseXML(data); `

Comment: @Abu - this is in jQuery 1.5 - what version are you using?

Comment: @Abu - if you can upgrade to 1.5, do so.  Otherwise you will need to use the browser's native methods of converting text to XML.

Comment: i dont think i will be able to upgrade just because some other developers are using  so how is that browser native method of converting to xml

Comment: @Abu - see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript) for a browser native method.  It also points out that a well-formed XML string wrapped as a jQuery object can be parsed using jQuery methods, so you should be able to get away with that.