# Issue with using jQuery to convert XML to HTML and back again (CDATA gets turned into HTML comments)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, cdata

I'm creating a plugin/bookmarklet that will take an XML document embedded within the `<textarea>` of a web page, make some changes to that XML, and then place the modified XML back in the `<textarea>` (to get submitted back to the server). My code works perfectly except when it comes to the [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdata) sections of the XML. When my jQuery code converts the XML into HTML, it converts all the CDATA sections into comments.  Thus

`<![CDATA[${Some Value}]]>`

becomes

```
<!--[CDATA[${Some Value}]]-->
```

Sometimes some of the data within the CDATA sections also gets messed up.  I read in some posts that this same thing happens when using AJAX calls to retrieve XML data.  The solution was to include the correct header type: `'Content-Type: text/xml'`  However, I don't know how to use that information to solve my problem - since I'm only working with XML already on the page.

For further background, the way I'm getting the XML out of the `<textarea>` on the page so that I can further manipulate it is with the following:

```
var myXml = $('textarea#myID').val();
myXml = $('<div id="myDiv" />').html(myXml);
```

and I place the modified XML back in the  with the following:

```
$('textarea#myID').val($('#myDiv').html());
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to get around the issue with how the CDATA sections get turned into `<!--comments-->` when the XML first gets converted into HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

This might help. You need to parse it as xml

Edit:

First parse your xml as I mentioned before, then manipulate the values as you need, then convert it back to string and add to your DIV using this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/x2s

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I wasn't able to get the plugin to work.  But this other S.O. post helped with converting the XML back into a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript