# Convert text string to xml using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, imagemapster

I'm using http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster and I'm wanting to extract the selected areas and format in to xml, this would ideally be on submit.

The below on click returns the selected areas and places the text into a span

```
$("#show_selected").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#selections').text($("#body_map").mapster("get"));
        });
```

The html for the above...

```
<div>
    <a id="show_selected" href="#">Click here to show selected items:</a>
    <span id="selections"></span>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that article!