# convert an XML jQuery Object to String

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, serialization, hash

I have an uploaded xml file that I'm perusing using jQuery via `var $ts = $.parseXML(filecontents)`

I have attempted to convert back to the original source when locating objects within the XML Document by utilising:

```
$('<div>').append($ts.find('Object').clone()).html();
```

In chrome, this works absolutely fine and I get the output as it looks in the original document. In firefox, it reorders the attributes of elements alphabetically.

Since I'm hashing this output, I need it to be the same as the input. Is this possible to enforce at all, or am I better with a different method of walking through this xml document?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert String to XML Document in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290321/convert-string-to-xml-document-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) API instead:

```
var foo = $ts.find("Object").get(0);
var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
var original = serializer.serializeToString(foo);
```